# I installed the wrong version of Ubuntu on my computer.

Tags: windows-8, system-installation

I am running windows 8 natively and have installed Ubuntu 14 from their download page. I believe I have installed the 32bit version instead of the 64bit version, because it will not load the option to boot into Ubuntu at startup. I have to restart holding shift to get into an option to reboot a sata drive that has this version of ubuntu on it. What is the best course of action here? Uninstall Ubuntu? Upgrade somehow?

Comment: 32 Bit verison is backward compatible, and works on all 64 bit hardware. Its some sort of bootloader issue. Try going into the Bios/UEFI settings, disable UEFI secureboot, and enable _legacy boot_, and then restart

Comment: I have done this already. That was the only way I could have even installed ubuntu in the first place.

Comment: In fact, Ubuntu is compatible with UEFI. Did you try it with Secure Boot enabled? Have you take the necessary steps mentioned in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI ?

Comment: Did you answer No when the Ubuntu installer asked if you want to install Grub?

Comment: I tried to install Ubuntu with secure boot enabled and was getting the error message no efi usb drive available. Once I disabled secure boot I was able to install ubuntu. I am using it right now. The problem as described above, is when I shut down for the night and want to reboot again, it only reboots into Windows 8 and does not give me an option to boot into ubuntu. I have to manually reboot into Ubuntu. I'd like to have an option to choose which OS I boot into at startup, which it is supposed to give me. I believe that 64bit Ubuntu would give me this option as it includes support for Uefi.

Comment: Katu- the installer did not ask me about installing grub. I used unetbootin.

Comment: I've had issues with 32bit EFI executable on an atom board. I sugest you download 64 bit image and try again. That way you can take full advantage of your hardware. Dont use `unetbootin`, use dd: `sudo dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M && sync`. Substitute for X depending on storage devices connected. Usually its `b` when you have just _one_ hdd and _one_ flash drive connected.
Important - dont substitute `a` for `X`. It will wipe out your windwos installation.

Comment: @katu I think 14.04 doesn't allow us _not_ to install grub. I hate it.

Comment: @Grace I'm pretty sure the message "no efi usb drive..." showed up because you used unetbootin to burn the image. EFI needs a `fat32` partition where it can find `.efi` files.

Comment: @JayAurabind I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, so I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that command line. Would it just be easier to reinstall 64bit ubuntu from windows?

Additionally, unetbootin allowed me to burn the ubuntu installation in fat32.

Comment: That command is for writing bootable image to a flash media. Since you are not experienced with command line, proceed as mentioned in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows after downloading 64 bit iso

Comment: I will try that. As an aside, this will be the third program I will be using to make an install disk. The other two were LiLi and unetbootin. Both were also suggestions of this same website.

Comment: dear friend follow the below link and try it first.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use boot-repair from an ubuntu live usb or easyBCD from Windows.

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Comment: I have installed 64 bit ubuntu, but it has not fixed the issue. I went back into UEFI and changed boot order to legacy, so now it at least boots into Ubuntu first. I don't know what else to do to make it give me a choice of OS to boot into, but this is at least a work around.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bumping this but I seem to have ruined windows 8 and cannot access the UEFI settings anymore. Is this fixable?

Comment: Make a bootable usb key with windows 8 repair (16Go at least I think) or use the installation CD to fix it.

Comment: I don't have a windows install disk. Windows recovery media was installed on a separate partition.